# Hangman blank space

Tags: matlab

While people are writing hangman drawing code I am trying simple word problem and failing.
I want to write a function that will take a word and letter and will check if the letter is there or not and display the word accordingly. The word can have upper case or lower case letter. However, the letter being tested is always lower case. Now an example,

```
    function out=hangman(word,letter)
 word='elEphaNt'
 letter='e'
 out='e_E_____'
```

The code I wrote:

```
    function board=hangman(word,letter)
    compare=((word==letter)| word==char(double(letter)-32));
    word=word(compare);
    end
```

however, this will output only 'eE' without the blank spaces. How can I include the blank spaces?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `out` as `word` and then replace non-matching characters. For testing the matching, use [`lower`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/lower.html) to convert everything to lowercase:

```
word = 'elEphaNt';
letter = 'e';
out = word;
out(~(lower(out)==lower(letter))) = '_';
```

---

In your code, you can achieve this replacing your last line by

```
word(~compare) = '_';
```

and probably assign `board = word;` to return that.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I tried this option!
Without this help I would spend another 1-2 hrs!